# Programmatically select text range in TextEdit

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, macos-carbon

Is it possible to select (Highlight) a range of text in TextEdit (by AppleScript,Cocoa or Carbon)?
I tryed this code but not work:

```
set value of attribute "AXSelectedTextRange" to {selStart, selLen}
```

It seems this attribute is readonly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how to do it with AppleScript (should be possible though), with the accessibility APIs, you could do something like this:

```
AXUIElementRef systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide();
AXUIElementRef focussedElement = NULL;
AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&focussedElement);
CFRange range = CFRangeMake(0, 10);
AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(focussedElement, kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute, AXValueCreate(kAXValueCFRangeType, &range));
CFRelease(focussedElement);
CFRelease(systemWideElement);
```

That would select the first 10 characters if the TextEdit window is focussed.

Comment: @omz plese check my issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274564/i-am-not-able-to-get-the-range-of-selected-text-in-textedit-application-from-my

Comment: It doesn't work in the sandboxed application even though accessibility permission is set. Any way to do it in the sandbox?

Comment: @WojciechKulik nope, you can't have both. if your app is sandboxed, you can't even prompt for AX permissions. it's one or the other.

Comment: @godbout actually you can prompt for AX permission. I use it to be able to simulate keys, and everything works, but not selecting text :)

Comment: @WojciechKulik i've never been able to. although i didn't dig any further as Apple doesn't allow apps that use the AX on the App Store (after 2012). but i know each time i start a new app that needs the AX, i'm getting reminded about the sandbox thing because the prompt, in my case, doesn't appear as long as i didn't switch the sandboxing off.

Comment: I can't get this to work with `AXTextArea`, but with `AXTextField` it works.