# Can't set settable accessibility attribute in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, accessibility

After reading the question “[Programmatically select text range in TextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487350/programmatically-select-text-range-in-textedit)”, I am curious why the *AXSelectedTextRange* attribute can’t be set in AppleScript even though the properties indicate it is settable.

Open a TextEdit document, type a few lines, highlight a portion and run the script below to test.

```
activate application "TextEdit"
tell application "System Events"
    set attr to attribute "AXSelectedTextRange" of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Untitled" of application process "TextEdit"
    attr's properties -- determine if settable
    set attr's value to {1, 2}
    delay 1
    attr's value
end tell
```

Is there something different about how AppleScript handles accessibility attributes  that I am misssing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the requested class (an *NSValue* that contains an object of class *NSRange* [or *CFRange* in Carbon]) does not exist in AppleScript. The class *list* in AppleScript equals the class *NSArray* in Objective-C.

Another example:

```
set value of attribute "AXPosition" of window 1 of application process "TextEdit" to {30, 30}
```

does nothing because the value must be an *NSPoint*.

When getting an attribute value in AppleScript, “System Events” converts *NSRange*, *NSpoint*, *NSSize* or *NSRect* to an *NSArray* that contains numbers (an AppleScript *list*), but does not convert a list to these types when you want to set the value.

- In **[NSAccessibility Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSAccessibility_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSAccessibilityAllowedValuesAttribute)**: NSAccessibilitySelectedTextRangeAttribute : The range of selected text (NSValue). The class NSValue may contain an object among these classes (NSRange, NSpoint, NSSize or NSRect)
- In **[Carbon Accessibility Reference](http://75.137.144.72/dump/Mac/OS%20X/Developer/Documentation/ReleaseNotes/AssistiveAPI.html#AXValueType)**: kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute : CFTypeRef : The range of the currently selected text (start & end character positions). This attribute is usually settable. The value is an encoded CFRange structure.

So it is possible in Objective-C,  AppleScriptObjC or any other language that can use the Cocoa or Carbon API, like **UI Browser** – but not in AppleScript.

Comment: Really great answer to the question!

Comment: thats very useful!!

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is. The exact reason I don't know but for a few years many scripters asked the same question (source:macscripter). It seems that even if the property settable is set to true the value for AXSelectedTextRange attribute seems to be read-only.

Comment: Thanks DJ. I can set it through the Attributes Drawer of UI Browser, just not through AS, weird.

Comment: That does not answer the question (which is “why”), it just confirms the fact there is an issue. @jackjr300’s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10511156/990363) does, though.